Configuration file of Python app shared across sub-packages
I am building an app to control some hardware. I have different kinds of hardware that I implemented in packages: motors and measurement devices. My file structure is as follow:
name_of_my_app/
    __init__.py
    main.py
    config.ini
    CONFIG.py
    motors/
        __init__.py
        one_kind_of_motor.py
    measurement_devices/
        __init__.py
        one_kind_of_measurement_device.py

I would like to have a single configuration file (ini) to store settings of the motors and measurement devices.
I started with the answer from u/symmitchry on that reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/2hjxk5/whats_the_proper_way_to_use_configparser_across/ as it seemed the most sensible thing to do. From what I understand, I could have a config.ini at the root of my app together with a CONFIG.py. CONFIG.py would take care of reading the settings from config.ini and make them available through an import of CONFIG.py. This works when I import the configuration from main.py. However, when I try to import the configuration from one_kind_of_motor.py with:
from ... import CONFIG

as suggested by @f3lix in this post: Importing modules from parent folder, I get a:
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

That is when I added the __init__.py at the root hoping it would solve my issue, but it didn't. I also tried with .. and . instead of ... and the only thing it did was to show how little I understand about this topic... (it keeps throwing the same error above).
Currently, to work around this problem, I read the specific settings I need from config.ini in every file. But I know it is sub-optimal.
I program in Python like a scientist, i.e. I don't have a software developer background and I normally use basic Python, but I'd like to learn clean ways of disseminating my research. I've seen a number of posts about similar questions (and you can call me out for this), but I failed to understand their answer. Can you please explain this to me in Layman's term?
EDIT: In response to the thorough answer from @ImpeccableChicken, I created a simplified file-structure and uploaded it on GitHub to demonstrate the problem. Using
from .. import CONFIG

produces an error
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

I am using a Windows machine and I execute my scripts from Visual Code.

How are you running your app?

I installed Visual Code and I press Run..Run Without Debugging.

This answer, together with its top comments, explains relative imports quite well.  Crucially, for relative imports, the dots indicate that the import system should move up in the package hierarchy, not in the filesystem tree.
Importing The File
The Problem
Assuming that you're importing one_kind_of_motor.py in main.py:

Running python main.py adds the parent directory of main.py to sys.path (i.e. name_of_my_app/ will be searched for packages and modules).
Within the __main__ module (corresponding to the main.py file), import motors.one_kind_of_motor creates the package motors with submodule motors.one_kind_of_motor.  The package motors has no parent package; this is apparent from the fact that its name contains no dots.  The module motors.one_kind_of_motor has motors as its parent.
During the import of motors.one_kind_of_motor, from .. import CONFIG indicates that the import system should move up two levels in the package hierarchy.  The first . corresponds to the package motors, which is the parent of the current module.  The second . corresponds to the parent of motors, but motors has no parent package, resulting in an error.

It might be helpful to remember that, in most cases, the number of leading dots in a relative-import statement cannot exceed the number of dots in the name of the module containing that statement.
(Although this guideline is quite helpful, it is not true in the general case; see __package__ and __spec__, for example.)
One important thing to note is that the root cause of the problem is not the relative-import statement in one_kind_of_motor.py, but rather the way in which the module is imported in main.py.  The relative import in one_kind_of_motor.py fails because one_kind_of_motor.py is imported as motors.one_kind_of_motor in another file.
A Multiple-Package Solution
If you are only ever going to run top-level scripts (i.e. scripts directly in name_of_my_app/), you can import the configuration from one_kind_of_motor.py with
import CONFIG

When running python main.py, the import succeeds because name_of_my_app/ is in sys.path.
(For this solution, the __init__.py file in name_of_my_app/ is not necessary.)
A Single-Package Solution
If you want the relative import to work, you can avoid the error by ensuring that all files intended for importing are nested in a directory adjacent to the scripts.  For example, you can arrange your project as follows:
name_of_my_app/
    main.py
    devices/
        __init__.py
        config.ini
        CONFIG.py
        motors/
            __init__.py
            one_kind_of_motor.py
        measurement_devices/
            __init__.py
            one_kind_of_measurement_device.py

You can then adjust any imports in main.py accordingly.  With this structure, you can import the configuration from one_kind_of_motor.py with
from .. import CONFIG

When running python main.py, one_kind_of_motor.py now corresponds to the module devices.motors.one_kind_of_motor, and the relative-import statement is equivalent to
from devices import CONFIG

Running The File
The Problem
Assuming that you're running one_kind_of_motor.py as a script:

Running python one_kind_of_motor.py adds the parent directory of one_kind_of_motor.py to sys.path (i.e. name_of_my_app/motors/ will be searched for packages and modules).
Within the __main__ module (corresponding to the one_kind_of_motor.py file), from .. import CONFIG indicates that the import system should move up two levels in the package hierarchy.  The first . corresponds to the parent of __main__.  In this case, the import system cannot find the parent package of __main__, since __main__.__spec__ is None.  This behavior is explained in the Python documentation:


Note that __main__.__spec__ is always None in the last case, even if the file could technically be imported directly as a module instead. Use the -m switch if valid module metadata is desired in __main__.

A Solution
To avoid the error, you can invoke the python command with the -m switch and supply the module name.  Specifically, adjust the import statements and project structure as described in one of the solutions above, and ensure that you are in the name_of_my_app/ directory.  Then, for the multiple-package case, run
python -m motors.one_kind_of_motor

or, for the single-package case, run
python -m devices.motors.one_kind_of_motor

Doing this will ensure that the __main__ module (corresponding to the one_kind_of_motor.py file) contains valid module metadata (as explained here).
However, the documentation mentions an important caveat associated with this approach:

Note also that even when __main__ corresponds with an importable module and __main__.__spec__ is set accordingly, they’re still considered distinct modules.

A consequence of this is that, if one_kind_of_motor.py is part of an import cycle (i.e. running one_kind_of_motor.py indirectly causes itself to be imported), you would end up with two copies of all classes and functions defined in one_kind_of_motor.py.  If an import cycle is necessary (avoid it if you can), you can define an entry-point function in one_kind_of_motor.py and call this function from main.py or another top-level script.  That is, in one_kind_of_motor.py, create a function that contains the desired entry-point code:
# Name this whatever makes sense
def main():
    ...

Then, somewhere in main.py, or in another script in name_of_my_app/, call this function:
import devices.motors.one_kind_of_motor
...
# Call the entry point
# Alternatively, call this only for certain script arguments or other conditions
devices.motors.one_kind_of_motor.main()

Now, rather than running one_kind_of_motor.py directly, run the top-level script that contains the import and entry-point call.

Thank you for the detailed answer @ImpeccableChicken. It is clear, but somehow, it doesn't work for me. I must be making the mistake, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I created a repository to show my problem. When I do the import from one_kind_of_motor.py with from .. import CONFIG, I get: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package. I am on Windows if that matters. Would you mind checking my repository? I will update my post accordingly if you find something relevant.

@Omnistic, I never considered that you might be executing one_kind_of_motor.py directly.  I've updated my answer to include a solution for that case as well.

Thank you @ImpeccableChicken for your answer. In VS Code Terminal, if I type python -m devices.motors.one_kind_of_motor it works and no more errors are thrown. However, I am still processing all this information. Do people who program in Python with VS Code generally run their script with the terminal instead of using Run..Run Without Debugging?

@Omnistic, I've never used VS Code, but it seems like this answer might help you to run any file as a module (although it requires that you install an extension).

Thank you @ImpeccableChicken. I don't know how I got that far into Python without ever using a terminal and let alone "-m". Much appreciated.

I am not familiar with VS code but the run configuration should be made to use the -m switch. What VS is doing is probably python.exe main.py from the name_of_my_app folder. You must instead run python -m name_of_my_app.main # note no .py. This tells python that in the package name_of_my_app run the module main.py as script. The parent package that python is looking for is exactly the name_of_my_app (should only contain characters that can appear in a python package name).

Thank you @Mr_and_Mrs_D for your answer. I understood that this -m is important and I shall learn more about it.
